# Why if I press F5 the servlet session ends?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

When I login from index.jsp, I can see the confirmation saying that the login was successful but if I press the F5 button the previous session is not considered and new session is created... so I have to login again and again if I press F5...

How can I make the session persistent?

index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ page session="true"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title> Practica3 </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu").click(function(event) {
        $('#content').load('Content',{content: $(this).attr('id')});
           });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

   <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
   <div id="wrapper">

         <!-- Begin Header -->
         <div id="header">

               This is the Header        

         </div>
         <!-- End Header -->

         <!-- Begin Navigation -->
         <div id="navigation">

         <jsp:include page="menu3.jsp" />

         </div>
         <!-- End Navigation -->

         <!-- Begin Faux Columns -->
         <div id="faux">

               <!-- Begin Left Column -->
               <div id="leftcolumn">



               </div>
               <!-- End Left Column -->

               <!-- Begin Content Column -->
               <div id="content">

               <jsp:include page="login.jsp" />

               </div>
               <!-- End Content Column -->



               <!-- Begin Right Column -->
               <div id="rightcolumn">




               </div>
               <!-- End Right Column -->

         </div>    
         <!-- End Faux Columns --> 

         <!-- Begin Footer -->
         <div id="footer">

               This is the Footer       

         </div>
         <!-- End Footer -->

   </div>
   <!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

menu.jsp:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu").click(function(event) {
        $('#content').load('Content',{content: $(this).attr('id')});
        });
});
</script>


<%HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
System.out.println("cargamos menu.jsp");
System.out.println("        (menu.jsp)Sesion:"+session);
System.out.println("Sesion(user):"+session.getAttribute("user"));
if ((session != null) && (session.getAttribute("user")!=null)) {

%>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <a class="menu" id="logout.jsp" href=#> Logout </a> </td>
</tr>
</table>    
<% }
else {%>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <a class="menu" id="form.jsp" href=#> Registration </a> </td>
<td> <a class="menu" id="login.jsp" href=#> Login </a> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<%}; %>
```

login.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="models.BeanLogin" %>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#content').load('logincontroller',$("#registerForm").serialize());
        }
    });
}

);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<% 
BeanLogin login = null;
if (request.getAttribute("login")!=null) {
    login = (BeanLogin)request.getAttribute("login");
}
else {
    login = new BeanLogin();
}
%>

<form id=registerForm action="/Practica3/logincontroller" method="POST">
<table>
<tr> 
<td> User id </td> 
<td> <input type="text" name="user" value="<%=login.getUser() %>" id="user" class="required" minlength="5"/> </td> 
<%  
    if ( login.getError()[0] == 1) {
        %> 
        <td class="error"> Invalid username or password. </td>  
        <% 
    }
%>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Password </td> 
<td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
    value="<%=login.getPassword()%>" id="password" class="required" minlength="8" /></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

loginOk.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#navigation').load('menu.jsp');   
});
</script>

Logged in!
```

loginController.jsp:

```
    /**
     * Servlet implementation class logincontroller
     */
    public class logincontroller extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static DAO Dao;

        /**
         * @throws Exception 
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public logincontroller() throws Exception {
            super();
            Dao = new DAO();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            BeanLogin login = new BeanLogin();
            BeanUtilities.populateBean(login, request);
            try {
                if (login.isComplete() && checkLogin(login)) {

                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                    session.setAttribute("user",login.getUser());
                    System.out.println("Se ha hecho el login."+session.toString());
                    System.out.println("User:"+session.getAttribute("user"));
                    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10);
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("loginOk.jsp");
                    if (dispatcher != null) dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                } else {

                request.setAttribute("login",login);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
                if (dispatcher != null) dispatcher.forward(request, response);

                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doGet(request,response);
        }

        protected boolean checkLogin(BeanLogin bean) throws SQLException{
            String query = "SELECT id,password FROM ts1.users;";

            ResultSet rs = Dao.executeQuerySQL(query);

            while(rs.next()){

                if (rs.getString(1).equals(bean.getUser()) && rs.getString(2).equals(bean.getPassword())){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            int[] errors = bean.getError();
            errors[0]++;
            bean.setError(errors);
            return false;
        }


    }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Practica3</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Content</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Content</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.Content</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Content</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Content</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>formcontroller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>formcontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.formcontroller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>formcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/formcontroller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>logincontroller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>logincontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.logincontroller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>logincontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logincontroller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>closesession</display-name>
    <servlet-name>closesession</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.closesession</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>closesession</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/closesession</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>logoutcontroller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>logoutcontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.logoutcontroller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>logoutcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logoutcontroller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method setMaxInactiveInterval() accepts time as seconds. You are setting the maximum inactive time for the session to 10 seconds. Set it to a time more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you press F5 on the page that `loginController` **forwards** to, which is supposed to be `loginOK.jsp`. And you might think that you refreshed the page `loginOK.jsp`, which is absolutely not. In fact, you just refreshed the `loginController` servlet.

The reason is that in your `loginController`, you use **forward** instead redirect. The url on your browser when your `loginOK.jsp` shows up is still `loginController` instead of `loginOK.jsp`. When you refresh this page, `loginController` gets refreshed. As a result a fresh request is created for `loginController`, a new **login** object is created. When you check/validate that **login** object in your `loginController`, it will fail the check/validation. Therefore, `loginController` forwards to `login.jsp` by your `else` statement.

One possible solution is to use redirect instead of forward:
`response.sendRedirect(...);`

However, I suggest that you redesign the login flow following the MVC pattern and do not put java snippet/code in your jsp page.
Good luck.